# Accept payment with a dialogflow chatbot

Tags: payment, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I have a chatbot build using **Dialogflow** that let's user's book a room from my customers hotel. Right now it just generates the amount the user has to pay based on his/her booking. Payment is made later.

I would like to add the option for users to pay from the chatbot itself, and send response to user whether the payment was successful or not.

How can this be done ?

Comment: The person who down-voted. Please leave a comment so I can know what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making payment through the chatbot is not considered safe (atleast i think so), you should generate a payment link, ask the user to make payment, give a button to user to click once the payment is done, and check if its really complete.
Before the payment is done, save the details into a database, so that you can later retrieve it and continue the conversation. You need to check this once user clicks the button after payment.

However you can get amount, and password from user and call some API to make payment.

Let us know what other issues are you facing.

Comment: Yes, this option did come up. If we proceed this way then how do I continue the same conversation once the user has made payment or if payment failed or user aborted etc.

Comment: i have updated the answer, also it seems logical dont know why it has been downvoted.

Comment: Thanks @sid8491 this sounds good to me, I'll check it out and accept the answer once I am done. I can not get to this right away

Comment: So I've implemented this now by generating a secured payment link and providing it to the user in response. Also I am accepting this answer.

Comment: @Thanthu glad to be of help, please upvote the answer as well, it would help me and others :)

Comment: oh yeah, i've noticed, same happened with your question as well :)